# SBT aggregating subproject

Tags: scala, sbt

Given a project structure:

```
rootProject
  aggregatingSubProject
    subA
    subB
  subC
```

How do I run the `package` task for `aggregatingSubProject` and all its aggregated projects, without specifying them by hand?

So far I can only have `subA` and `subB` built when doing `package` in the `rootProject` - regardless if I put `.aggregate(subA, subB)` in `aggregatingProject`'s `build.sbt`.

I need the `rootProject` to define common settings for the build and I want to build multiple projects (some aggregating other projects, like `aggregatingSubProject` does) in a single build.

EDIT: I need to do this without specifying all the sub-sub-projects in the root build.sbt. I'd like to define subA and subB in aggregatingSubProject/build.sbt.

Using sbt `0.13.16`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this in `build.sbt`:

```
val rootProject = project in file(".")
val aggregatingSubProject = project
val subC = project
```

and this in `aggregatingSubProject/build.sbt`:

```
aggregateProjects(subA, subB)

val subA = project
val subB = project
```

You can run `aggregatingSubProject/package` and get:

```
> aggregatingSubProject/package
[info] Updating {file:/s/t-subaggregate/}subB...
[info] Updating {file:/s/t-subaggregate/}aggregatingSubProject...
[info] Updating {file:/s/t-subaggregate/}subA...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Packaging /s/t-subaggregate/aggregatingSubProject/subA/target/scala-2.12/suba_2.12-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /s/t-subaggregate/aggregatingSubProject/subB/target/scala-2.12/subb_2.12-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Done updating.
[info] Packaging /s/t-subaggregate/aggregatingSubProject/target/scala-2.12/aggregatingsubproject_2.12-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
```

Comment: Thx for the reply! Can I somehow do that without specifying all the sub-sub-projects in the root `build.sbt`? I'd like to define `subA` and `subB` in `aggregatingSubProject/build.sbt` (that's what I'm doing now and it doesn't seem to work as exepcted)